# Can I receive email from an MS Exchange server using POP or IMAP on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, exchange, imap, pop3, google-sync

Is there a way to have my iPhone access my work email off of an Exchange server?

The iPhone only allows you to set up 1 MS Exchange account.  Currently I have this spot taken up by my Google Sync Account.  I use my google account for mail, contacts, and calenders.

So I would like to setup my work email on my iPhone as either a POP or IMAP account.  Using these settings my iPhone never finishes verifying account information.  I have checked that my exchange account is setup for POP and it is.  I also know that I have setup blackberry email for users at the office using the POP protocol so it should be doable.  If I were to remove my Google sync account and use my work account as an exchange account it would work just fine.

Any ideas / suggestions.

If I can't find any solutions I was just going to have my work email forwarded to my gmail account but I was hoping for a solution a bit more eloquent than that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your iPhone can receive mail from an Exchange server via POP or IMAP provided they are turned on.

If you have already set up POP with the Blackberries you simply need to use the same settings you would have entered for your Service Books on your iPhone.

If you don't have IMAP enabled you can turn it on (instructions vary depending on your version) and then use the same settings.

For more info on enabling IMAP on Exchange check your documentation or TechNet: [Exchange 2003](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123880.aspx) or [Exchange 2007](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124489.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

From any machine that has telnet installed, (or if it doesn't, install it), simply type at a command line -

```
telnet my_work_server 25
telnet my_work_server 110
telnet my_work_server 143
```

Top two are for SMTP / POP3 and the lower is for IMAP.

If you get request time out, the address is wrong or the service has not been enabled - If smtp is not working, I would double check that you have the correct address.

Exchange, by default has POP3 and IMAP disabled.

Anyway, I set up my brother's IPod Touch to Exchange and additional accounts no problem - so I am sure that this is a setting issue and nothing else.

Comment: Just using Vista's default telnet client.  telnet server 25 spits back invalid command.

Comment: can you post a link to a screenshot or post the exact error message you see? doing SMTP should work, otherwise other people will not be able to send you messages

Comment: I just get an invalid command from telnet server.com 25.  Here is a link to my account's properties on the exchange server.  It says POP3 and IMAP4 are enabled using protocol defaults.  http://picasaweb.google.com/ctkahler/Misc#5389494709467430178
Each time I try and add the account though I get IMAP account verification failed.  The IMAP server is not responding.

Answer (score 0):

You could move your GMail account away from ActiveSync, thus freeing up the single Exchange account for your work account. You'll then have to handle your email, calendar and contacts separately:

[Use IMAP to sync your mail](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=77702).

[Use CalDAV to sync your calendar](http://www.google.com/support/mobile/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151674).

[Use iTunes to sync your contacts](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1245).

This is how I had my iPhone set up before moving to ActiveSync, and it works reasonably well.

Comment: I do not want to use iTunes.